# Loop functionality and tallying in javascript rock paper scissors game() function

Tags: javascript

Just as a foreword, I'm very new to programming so apologies if the error is something simple that I've simply overlooked.  Also in advance I know the game function is a mess right now, I copied it in the state that it's in now after I've fiddled with it for a couple days.

I've been working on the odin project rock paper scissors project and although I've developed a single round function that works well, I haven't been able to make the overarching game function work properly.  I've tried shifting syntax around and I suspect that the problem lies somewhere with the scope of specific variables but I haven't been able to figure out a way that works as of yet.  I've also been doing research for the last few days trying to figure out how to do it while I was streamlining the single round but I wasn't able to find a query that worked with how my code is set up.

I've put everything within the same function but I can't seem to get the loop to work properly when I do, and I've tried pulling variables out from local to global scale but haven't been successful- as I mentioned though the function for a single round works without error and returns a correct string no matter the outcome so I have a hunch the error does lie somewhere in the variable scale and I just haven't been able to pinpoint it.

My game function, which is about the fifth or sixth rendition that doesn't work:

```js
function game() {
  let playerScore = 0;
  let computerScore = 0;
  let roundResult = computerPlay();

  for (let counter = 0; counter <= 5; ++counter) {
    computerPlay();

    if (roundResult === 'You win, rock beats scissors' || roundResult === 'You win, paper beats rock.' || roundResult === 'You win, scissors beats paper.') {
      ++playerScore;
    } else if (roundResult === 'You lose, paper beats rock.' || roundResult === 'You lose, scissors beats paper.' || roundResult === 'You lose, rock beats scissors.') {
      ++computerScore
    }

    if (playerScore > computerScore) {
      return ('You win ' + playerScore + ' to ' + computerScore + '.');
    } else if (playerScore < computerScore) {
      return ('You lose ' + computerScore + ' to ' + playerScore + '.');
    } else {
      return 'It was a tie, you both won the same number of rounds.';
    }
  }
}

// and the single round (computerPlay) function that works fine:

function computerPlay() {
  let playerInput = prompt('Enter your selection of rock, paper, or scissors.');
  let playerTrimmed = playerInput.trim();
  let playerSelection = playerTrimmed.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

  let playerScore = 0;
  let computerScore = 0;

  if (playerSelection === 'R' || playerSelection === 'P' || playerSelection === 'S') {
    let myArray = ['R', 'P', 'S'];
    let computerSelection = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

    if (playerSelection === 'R') {
      if (computerSelection === 'S') {
        ++playerScore;
        return 'You win, rock beats scissors.';
      } else if (computerSelection === 'P') {
        ++computerScore;
        return 'You lose, paper beats rock.';
      } else {
        return 'Tie.';
      }
    } else if (playerSelection === 'P') {
      if (computerSelection === 'R') {
        ++playerScore;
        return 'You win, paper beats rock.';
      } else if (computerSelection === 'S') {
        ++computerScore;
        return 'You lose, scissors beats paper.';
      } else {
        return 'Tie.';
      }
    } else if (playerSelection === 'S') {
      if (computerSelection === 'P') {
        ++playerScore;
        return 'You win, scissors beats paper.';
      } else if (computerSelection === 'R') {
        ++computerScore;
        return 'You lose, rock beats scissors.';
      } else {
        return 'Tie.';
      }
    }

  } else {
    //makes sure player entered a string starting with a valid letter (r, p, or s)
    alert('Please make sure you enter a valid selection.');
  }
}

game()
```

Comment: The `return` statement will end a function's execution, even if it's inside a loop, no further iterations of the loop will be run. So the `game()` function loop will only run once, then return a string. You may want to move that  `playerScore > computerScore` check out of (and after) the loop.

Comment: You can avoid all the if-then horror by defining winning matchups - `const winCombos = ["PR", "RS", "SP"]` and then checking if `winCombos.indexOf(selection)!=-1` and if both selections are the same. That should cover all the scenarios.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/pfzq69yt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like DBS said the return statement will stop your function and your loop with it, so try it like this:

```
function game() {
  let playerScore = 0;
  let computerScore = 0;
  let roundResult = computerPlay();

  for (let counter = 0; counter <= 5; ++counter) {
    computerPlay();

    if (roundResult === 'You win, rock beats scissors' || roundResult === 'You win, paper beats rock.' || roundResult === 'You win, scissors beats paper.') {
      ++playerScore;
    } else if (roundResult === 'You lose, paper beats rock.' || roundResult === 'You lose, scissors beats paper.' || roundResult === 'You lose, rock beats scissors.') {
      ++computerScore
    }
  }

  if (playerScore > computerScore) {
    return ('You win ' + playerScore + ' to ' + computerScore + '.');
  } else if (playerScore < computerScore) {
    return ('You lose ' + computerScore + ' to ' + playerScore + '.');
  } else {
    return 'It was a tie, you both won the same number of rounds.';
  }
}
```

Like this it will return the result only when the loop is finished.

(And btw the playerScore and computerScore variables in your computerPlay() function are useless :p)